# How to change the mysql root password based database

Tags: mysql

i need to change the MySQL default username(root) and password based on my database.

thanks

Comment: Please add what you have tried

Comment: what is your environment and your mysql version?

Comment: i have tried following ways
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/DB?useOldAliasMetadataBehavior=true"
db.default.user=root

Comment: play with scala  and windows environment and my MySQL version 5.6

Answer (score -1):

mysqladmin -u user_name -h host_name password "newpwd"